# Disable smart indentation in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: php, netbeans-8

I use Netbeans 8.2 for PHP coding for a long while. Now I set it up again on a new laptop and I'm again stuck with disabling the smart-indentation. I can't find any option within Netbeans nor some hint on the web.

My goal: I need the auto-indentation (insert tabs after newline), but not the "smart" indentation, that sometimes eats tabs at the beginning of the line.

**Example:**

I type the following in the editor (the pipe | is the caret):

```php
<div>
    <?php if(true) { ?>
        <div|

    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

When I now type the closing `>`, the smart indentation do a back indent on the line:

```php
<div>
    <?php if(true) { ?>
    <div>|

    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

And that's the annoying behaviour I try to disable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you mean by "smart" indentation so this might not rise to the level of an answer, but in any case it's too big for a comment, and it may point you in the right direction.

To adjust your indentation settings for PHP code on NetBeans:

- Select **Tools > Options > Editor**
- Click the **Formatting** tab.
- Select ***PHP*** from the **Language** drop list, and ***Tabs and Indents*** from the **Category** drop list.
- Uncheck the **Use All Language Settings** check box.
- You can then play with the settings for various fields, and see how your changes impact the sample code displayed on the right side of the **Options** screen. For example:

  [image: PHP tabs and indents]
- Click the **Apply** button to implement your changes.

Notes:

- You might want to take a screen shot of the ***Tabs and Indents*** screen before making any changes so that you can revert to the default settings if necessary. There is no **Revert to Defaults** button.
- After making your changes to the tab and indentation rules you can leave the **Options** window open, and reformat your own code using **Alt** + **Shift** + **F**. If you don't like the results just undo the changes to your code (**Ctrl** + **Z**), refine the settings on the **Options** screen and reformat again.
- I couldn't get line wrapping to work after adjusting the **Right Margin** value with **Line Wrap** set to ***Anywhere***. I think there may be a bug.
- There are several other options available on the **Category** drop list (***Alignment***, ***Braces***, etc.) if you want to further override the default formatting rules for PHP.
- Whenever changing the code formatting rules:

  - Be mindful that this may result in a huge number of line changes within your source control system, so never combine code changes with non-trivial formatting changes.
  - In a team environment make sure everyone is using the same formatting rules.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I know this options page and played around a lot. But there is no way to achieve my goal. I added an example to my post to make it more clear.