# How to disable auto-indenting in NetBeans IDE 14?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-14

### Short Version

How do i disable automatic indenting when i press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in NetBeans IDE?

### Long Version

Consider some code, with my insertion caret at the end of the last line:

`byte[] data;`
`try {`
   `data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);`‸

When i press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it's because i want to insert a *carriage return*, and move the caret to the start of the next line:

`byte[] data;`
`try {`
   `data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
`​`‸

Except what happens in NetBeans, is that also automatically indents for me:

`byte[] data;`
`try {`
   `data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
<kbd>Tab</kbd>‸

How do i turn this off?

### Research Effort

- [Disable smart indentation in Netbeans 8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56850720/disable-smart-indentation-in-netbeans-8-2)
- Netbeans Narkive: [Disable all auto indenting](https://nbusers.netbeans.narkive.com/JrB7DmM6/disable-all-auto-indenting)
- Bugzilla: [Bug 231879 - Unable to disable all automatic indentation and random carriage returns across the editor](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=231879)
- [How to disable the annoying NetBeans auto-suggest while typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40191946/how-to-disable-the-annoying-netbeans-auto-suggest-while-typing)
- [How do I autoindent in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311912/how-do-i-autoindent-in-netbeans)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is straightforward to turn off automatic indentation in NetBeans 14, but the process is not intuitive for Java source. These settings must be applied in sequence after navigating to the **Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting** screen:

- Select **Language:** *All Languages* and **Category:** *Tabs and
  Indents*, and then uncheck the checkbox **Enable Indentation** and click the **Apply** button. This will turn off automatic indentation for all languages by default, but that global setting might still be overridden for individual languages.
- Select **Language:** *Java* and **Category:** *Tabs and Indents*, and then uncheck the checkboxes **Use all Languages Settings** and **Enable Indentation**, and click the **OK** button.

After making those changes the modified fields should look like this if you revisit the **Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting** screen:

- **Language:** *All Languages*

  [image: All Languages screen]
- **Language:** *Java*

  [image: Java screen]

Then, using your sample code, if the cursor is positioned at the end of the line containing `data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed:

- A new line will be inserted.
- The cursor will be positioned at the start of that new line.

This is the sample code I used:

```
package javaantapplication1;

import java.util.Base64;

public class JavaAntApplication1 {

    private static byte[] s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    byte[] data;

    try { 
        data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
        
    } 
}
```

Notes:

- The steps to re-enable automatic indentation are not the reverse of those described above. Instead, simply revisit the first screen shown above, check **Enable Indentation**, and click **OK**. That is sufficient to enable indentation for Java again.
- I don't think it is possible to have automatic indentation disabled only for Java source.
- While better than nothing, the GUI for configuring indentation in NetBeans is confusing and inflexible.